# ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, public-key

I'm trying to reach the Gitlab server to clone a repo in a Ubuntu 20.10 computer, but I always get the message:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So, I've tried to run the command `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`, but I've got the message:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable
```

I've tried in another computer with Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Is it possible you are on a network which is blocking traffic on port 22?

Comment: I've opened the port 22 on my computer.

Comment: it may be open on your computer, but is it possible the network you are on is blocking traffic on port 22?

Comment: I thought it too, but I've connected on github using the same door and it's working.

Comment: I have this same issue. I have been avoiding HTTPS for days but it seems that's my only alternative

Comment: My work connection requires me to turn on my proxy and all sorts of crazy stuff. Using my phone as a hotspot and turning off the proxy allowed me to connect successfully.

Comment: Imho you should contact your network administrator to solve the issue with them and not despite them.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I am connected to a remote machine via ssh (VPN turned on because it is located in the company). From the remote machine I tried to git clone (ssh) and got the following error message:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:<project-name>.git
Cloning into '<project-name>'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The following solution worked. I added the following to the ssh-config of the remote machine, which was described here: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/.

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

I am now able to git clone (ssh) projects from GitLab without any problems.

Comment: In `user` place your git user and in `IdentityFile` place `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` it worked for me

Answer (score 6):

If you can't use ssh right now,You can use HTTPS instead with:

```
git remote set-url origin <Clone HTTPS address>
```

Answer (score 5):

I would never be able to use SSH URL for any public Git repository hosting service (github.com, gitlab.com, ...) in a work environment.

If the issue persists with other services (`ssh -Tv git@github.com`), then SSH URLs are not allowed for you. Use an HTTPS URL.

But if on the same network, another server does work, then double-check the firewall rules for your particular machine. One might block SSH, while the other not.
(`ufw status verbose`)

Comment: I've enabled ssh and port 22 and it stills the same. On github it works properly.
The other computer is not on the same network, unfortunately, and the gitlab url is not the same. To check the network, I've tried with VPN on and off, didn't worked.

Comment: @LuisFelipe So your machine, you can contact github through SSH, but not gitlab.com?

Comment: Basically, yes. But I need both, one is for my job repo and the other are for personal and other jobs.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Can you ping gitlab.com?

Comment: Gitlab pinging normally. The gitlab URL that I need is the corporative one, in gitlab domain.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Do you mean it is not gitlab.com?

Comment: I was able to connect to gitlab.com after executing the command in this answer and accepting the fingerprint question.

Comment: @MaxJ OK: SSH is not blocked in your working environment (it is certainly blocked in mine)

Answer (score 3):

I was happily pushing and pulling to my (private) gitlab repo via SSH (Ubuntu with WSL2) until this error popped up. After about 5 minutes of trying to google the error, it just started working again!

If you've successfully pushed/pulled/cloned and confident its not a firewall issue, you might just need to go and make yourself a coffee and try again before losing hours on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple possible reasons for this:

1.) You are on a network which blocks traffic to port 22. Trying your connection from another network or device would be the best way to quickly test for this.

2.) The ssh service on your droplet is not running.

Solutions:

1. You can change the port that your ssh service listens on in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_conf or you can use other network to test this problem solution.
2. Configure your SSH key agian.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out, the server I've been trying to connect needs a proxy, which solved the problem. But I hope someone can get helped by this.

Answer (score 2):

After days of searching and set up several times by delete `.ssh` file and set up again, I found the problem was with the network where certain websites where blocked from accessing, so I unblocked it in the network provider in safe filter like webs for "address hiding" or "hacking".

Then `git clone` and `push` works as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, I could not connect to GitLab via SSH via the Windows PowerShell terminal.
The solution was to use HTTPS to access GitLab through the built-in extension in the VScode editor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was due to using a guest wifi network. After changing to a normal network, it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35024156)

Answer (score 0):

i changed ssh address to https solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error solved by the below points covered for me.

1. Connected to a personal mobile network from a broadband network.
2. Used HTTPS.